# Is there a way to distinctly(no duplicates) populate a winform Combobox with values from an excel Range?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

```
range = worksheet.get_Range("AQ105", "AQ108") as _Excel.Range;
                
comboBox9.Items.Clear();
 
foreach (_Excel.Range cell in range.Cells)
{                        
     comboBox9.Items.Add((cell.Value2).ToString() as string);                      
}
```

`ComboBox9` returns `15, 20, 25, 15`

Any way to *eliminate the duplicates* ? In this case `15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `HashSet<string>` in order to `Add` distinct `value`s only:

```
...

HashSet<string> distinct = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (_Excel.Range cell in range.Cells)
{
    string value = (cell.Value2).ToString();

    if (distinct.Add(value))
        comboBox9.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry it works, i have 30 comboBoxes .Do i have to repeat this for all or do you think of a way we can use this as a method?

Comment: @Kevin: if you have `30` (!) `ComboBox`es, *extracting a method* is a very typical practice: do not repeat yourself